# Change custom default R library with libPaths after version upgrade?

Tags: r

If I use `.libPaths()` to set a custom default package library location (e.g. /path/to/Library/R/3.6/site-library), would I need to manually change this after a major R version upgrade? (e.g. 3.6 -> 4.0) How do people usually manage this?

Comment: The easiest way is not to manually set a lib path; R by default will always put the version number in the path because generally packages with different version prefixes may not be compatible. But if you must sett up your own paths, then I would recommend you do the same. Keep the "x.y" part of the version number in the path. Do you set your libPaths each time you load and run R? Or if you have some startup script, you can call `getRversion()` to get set the current version number and dynamically build paths that way.

Comment: That is what I figured, Before, when I've let R organize packages I've never had to worry about versions in the path. I was planning on setting libPaths in .Rprofile when R loads. So I don't think I can run getRversion() there.

Comment: You can put a `.First` function inside your Rprofile file which would allow you to use `getRversion` to set the libPaths.